# Laravel insert to 3 related tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Hi guys I would like to know if anyone of you have tried inserting a record into a table in laravel using 3 related tables? Example

```
// Database Schema for Pharmacy
Schema::create('pharmacies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('address');
});

// Relationship in App\Pharmacy table
public function pharmacists() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pharmacist');

}
```

Now I have another table

```
Schema::create('pharmacists', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('pharmacy_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('pharmacy_id')->references('id')->on('pharmacies')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('fname');
});

// And this is the relationship in App\Pharmacist class
public function account() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Account');
}

public function pharmacy() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pharmacy');
}
```

And now for the third table

```
// This contain the foreign key for pharmacist_id
Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('pharmacist_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('pharmacist_id')->references('id')->on('pharmacists')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
});

// This is the relationship in App\Account class
public function pharmacists() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pharmacist');
}
```

Now I tried saving this using this code under AccountsController

```
$input = Request::all();

    $pharmacy = Pharmacy::create([
                    "name" => "Wendies Chicken",
                    "address" => "My Address",                        
                ]);

    $pharmacists = new Pharmacist([
        "fname" => "Administrator",            
    ]);

    $account = new Account([
        "username" => "root",            
    ]);

    $pharmacists->account()->save($account);
    $pharmacy->pharmacists()->save($pharmacists);
```

But I get an error saying

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'pharmacist_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `accounts` (`username`, `pharmacist_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (root, 2015-08-09 05:13:31, 2015-08-09 05:13:31))
```

Dont know how to save this is just one saving. I would like to save the records in the 3 related tables. Can someone help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are executing this code

```
$pharmacists->account()->save($account);
$pharmacy->pharmacists()->save($pharmacists);
```

There is actually no data for **`pharmacy_id`** so that is the problem. So you should either change your schema for **`pharmacy_id`** and set it's value as **`default 0`**

```
$pharmacy = Pharmacy::create([
                "name" => "Wendies Chicken",
                "address" => "My Address",                        
            ]);

$pharmacy->pharmacists()->save([
    "fname" => "Administrator",            
]);

$pharmacy->pharmacists()->account()->save([
    "username" => "root",            
]);
```

Comment: This fix the problem thanks a lot although I did this instead $pharmacy->pharmacists()->save($pharmacists)->account()->save($account); and it seems to work also. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$input = Request::all();

$pharmacy = Pharmacy::create([
    "name"              => "Wendies Chicken",
    "address"           => "My Address",                        
]);

$pharmacists = Pharmacist::create([
    "pharmacy_id"       => $pharmacy->id,
    "fname"             => "Administrator",
]);

$account = Account::create([
    "pharmacist_id"     => $pharmacists->id
    "username"          => "root",            
]);
```