# Set a fixed value for a field in a multi-row insert in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have an array `$cart`:

```
$cart = [
    ["product_id" => 1, "price" => 20, "amount" => 5, "tax" => 15],
    ["product_id" => 2, "price" => 30, "amount" => 10, "tax" => 20],
    ...
];
```

I can do

```
DB::table('order_products')->insert($cart);
```

But I need to insert this array into a table that has the same columns + `order_id`. The `order_id` will be the same for all rows, it's the insert id of the previous query. Is it possible to set a fixed value for `order_id` for all rows?

Comment: Why don't you just get the order_id before you initialize `$cart`, and either do a foreach loop, add `order_id` in, or just include it as part of the array manually for reach row?

Comment: $cart is initialized before the insert that returns order_id; a foreach loop is unnecessary (and potentially costly), if there's a way to do it by somehow setting a fixed value in the SQL query.

Comment: Consider checking this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31901449/4875631

Comment: @FrankerZ So I'd do `order = new Order; ... order->save();`. And then? `order->order_products()->save($cart);` and the order_id would be copied from `order`?

Comment: Try it/review docs if it doesn't work.

Comment: If you use eloquent models, you would probably want to use [`createMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)

Comment: For some reason, `Order::create()` didn't work for me, but `$order = new Order; ... $order->save();` did. Then I did `$order->order_products()->createMany($cart);` and that worked fine, just had to set all fields apart from `order_id` to fillable. Thanks. Submit an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use eloquent models and your `Order` model has a *hasMany* relation `order_products()`, then you can use the [`createMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) method on the relation:

```
$order->order_products()->createMany($cart);
```

For `save()` and `saveMany()` methods as well as for `create()` and `createMany()`, if called on a relation, the foreign key (in your case `order_id`) will be set automatically taken from the parent `$order` entity.

In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) you will also find this note:

> Before using the `create` method, be sure to review the documentation
>   on attribute [mass
>   assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Most important is the `$fillable` property, which you already figured out.

Note that you should also be able to use `create()` for the order itself. I don't know why it didn't work for you. Check the `$fillable` property in the `Order` model. Also usually an order belongs to a user - so you would need to assign `user_id`, which might be missing in the array. What could work is

```
$order = Auth:user()->orders()->create($orderArray);
```

The `user_id` would be taken from `Auth:user()` and assigned to the order automatically.

Comment: Regarding the create(), this is my code: https://pastebin.com/SCB7WUEe. Laravel only saw the first element of the array, so the error was something along the lines of "status field doesn't have a default value"

Comment: `$order = Auth:user()->orders()->create($orderArray);` good point, I should add that relationship as well.

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich - I guess `status` is missing in `$fillable`. But your code is fine as it is. You win nothing using `create()`. What you though could do is: `$order = new Order; $order->fill($address); $order->user_id = $user_id; $order->status = config('app.default_status'); $order->save();` - and save some lines of code.

Comment: With `save()`, I don't need `status` in `$fillable`. Also, it doesn't come from user input/request (`$order->status = config('app.default_status');`)

Comment: I tried using create() with $orderData, and still got the same error. So I tried `$order = Auth::user()->orders()->create(["status"=>'test']);`, but I'm still getting **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'status' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `orders` (`user_id`) values (1))**

Comment: Apparently, adding status to $fillable helped, I wonder why though, since it doesn't come from user input at all.